# How gcc linker works in including files

Tags: c, gcc, linker, linker-errors

This is really a newbie question. I'm learning C, and I don't understand how to link together
different files.

I have a header like

```
/* file2.h */

int increment(int x);
```

and a C file

```
/* file2.c */

#include "file2.h"

int increment(int x)
{
    return x+1;
}
```

Now I want to include the header in `file1.c` in order to use the function `increment`.
From what I have understood I have to do something like:

```
/* file1.c*/

#include "file2.h"

int main()
{
    int y = increment(1);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile the whole thing, using

```
gcc -o program file1.c
```

I get an error message like

```
/tmp/ccDdiWyO.o: In function `main':
file1.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `increment'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However if I include also file2.c

```
/* file1.c*/

#include "file2.h"
#include "file2.c"  /* <--- here it is! */

int main()
{
    int y = increment(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works as expected.

But if I have understood only the header file (with only declarations in it) has to be included. So how can I inform `gcc` that the definition of function `increment` declared in `file2.h` is in `file2.c`?

Comment: I think your last sentence got cut off.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had problems while uploading the question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to compile them both directly:

```
$ gcc -o program file1.c file2.c
```

But for more complicated systems you might want to do it in steps.  Here's a simple command line recipe:

```
$ gcc -c file1.c
$ gcc -c file2.c
$ gcc -o program file1.o file2.o
```

Even better for something complicated like this would be to use [make](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=gnu+make+manual&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), though.

Aside from your specific problem, why are you using GCC?  You could use [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and get better error messages, faster compiling, and feel like you're living in the future!

Comment: Is there any difference in the library? I didn't know about this compiler.

Comment: @Matteo - clang is pretty much a drop-in replacement for gcc.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try :)
So if I write a Makefile I can define a variable at the beginning like `COMPILER = clang` and leave the rest of the file unchanged using the same options of `gcc`?

Comment: That will probably work, but `CC` is the canonical `make` variable for the C compiler.

Answer (score 2):

gcc -o program file2.c file1.c

this will compile file1.c and file2.c and link them together.